# Mixing async tasks with blocking sync task

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I am writing a set of async tasks that go away an download and parse data, however I am running in to a bit of a blank with the next step where I am updating a database.

The issue is that for the sake of performance I am using a TableLock to load rather large datasets, so what I am wanting to do is have my import service wait for the first Task to return, start the import. Should another Task complete while the first import is running the process joins a queue and waits for the import service is complete for task 1.

eg.

Async
 - Task1
 - Task2
 - Task3

Sync
 - ImportService

RunAsync Tasks

```
Task3 returns first > ImportService.Import(Task3)
Task1 return, ImportService is still running. Wait()
ImportService.Complete() event
Task2 returns. Wait()
ImportService.Import(Task1)
ImportService.Complete() event
ImportService.Import(Task2)
ImportService.Complete() event
```

Hope this makes sense!

Comment: You probably should consider [TPL DataFlow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh228603.aspx "Dataflow (Task Parallel Library)").

Answer (score 2):

You can't really use await here, but you can wait on multiple tasks to complete:

```
var tasks = new List<Task)();
// start the tasks however
tasks.Add(Task.Run(Task1Function);
tasks.Add(Task.Run(Task2Function);
tasks.Add(Task.Run(Task2Function);

while (tasks.Count > 0)
{
   var i = Task.WaitAny(tasks.ToArray()); // yes this is ugly but an array is required
   var task = tasks[i];
   tasks.RemoveAt(i);
   ImportService.Import(task); // do you need to pass the task or the task.Result
}
```

Seems to me however that there should be a better option. You could let the tasks and the import run and add a lock on the `ImportService` part for instance:

```
// This is the task code doing whatever
....
// Task finishes and calls ImportService.Import
lock(typeof(ImportService)) // actually the lock should probably be inside the Import method
{
   ImportService.Import(....);
}
```

There are several things bothering me with your requirements (including using a static ImportService, static classes are rarely a good idea), but without further details I can't provide better advice.

Comment: To OP: I agree with Eli that you should simply synchronize on the import, with each task acquiring the lock before importing as the last operation they do. Depending on the exact implementation, there may be variations on this theme that work better, but the above example is as good as can be reasonably provided unless you improve the question with more detail, including [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that clearly illustrates the question.

Comment: Thank you Eli and Peter.
I quite like the idea of locking the thread, this is what I originally had in mind but didn't think it was possible with Tasks, you learn something new every day. Thanks! :)

Comment: @Al. you should consider whether you need a lock at the application level at all. I don't know what database you are using but one thing databases are good for is dealing with concurrent operations. If you lock at the application level, assuming the lock is even required, then you are restricted to a single application running concurrently. You cannot scale to multiple servers without having to rewrite the lock mechanism. Perhaps your question should be: how can I get my query to run without TableLock, or without application level locks.

Answer (score 1):

While this is likely not the most graceful solution, I would try launching the work tasks and have them place their output in a ConcurrentQueue.  You could check the queue for work on a timer until all tasks are completed.

```
var rand = new Random();
var importedData = new List<string>();
var results = new ConcurrentQueue<string>();
var tasks = new List<Task<string>>
{
    new Task<string>(() =>
    {
        Thread.Sleep(rand.Next(1000, 5000));
        Debug.WriteLine("Task 1 Completed");
        return "ABC";
    }),
    new Task<string>(() =>
    {
        Thread.Sleep(rand.Next(1000, 5000));
        Debug.WriteLine("Task 2 Completed");
        return "FOO";
    }),
    new Task<string>(() =>
    {
        Thread.Sleep(rand.Next(1000, 5000));
        Debug.WriteLine("Task 3 Completed");
        return "BAR";
    })
};

tasks.ForEach(t =>
{
    t.ContinueWith(r => results.Enqueue(r.Result));
    t.Start();
});

var allTasksCompleted = new AutoResetEvent(false);
new Timer(state =>
{
    var timer = (Timer) state;
    string item;

    if (!results.TryDequeue(out item)) 
        return;

    importedData.Add(item);
    Debug.WriteLine("Imported " + item);

    if (importedData.Count == tasks.Count)
    {
        timer.Dispose();
        Debug.WriteLine("Completed.");
        allTasksCompleted.Set();
    }
}).Change(1000, 100);


allTasksCompleted.WaitOne();
```